# gulp-svg-sprites outputs [Object object] instead of icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gulp

I want to use `gulp-svg-sprites` to build svg sprite with `symbols`. But I get wrong output: icons aren't generated ([Object object] in `<symbol>`), paths are wrong, seems like some compiler doesn't work.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprites');

gulp.task('sprites', function () {
    return gulp.src('icons/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite({mode: "symbols"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("images"));
});
```

generated `symbols.html` contains

```
<h4>Files Generated:</h4>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="{config.svg.symbols}">{config.svg.symbols}</a></li>
    </ol>
```

generated `symbols.svg` contains

```
<symbol id="big_icon_1" viewBox="0 0 55 59">

      [object Object] [object Object]

  </symbol>
```

and such is the final output, without any changes.
Maybe something is missing. I've already have installed *node-gyp* although I don't need it (I try everithing to solve the problem).
What it can be? What is missing? Maybe there are some other ways to generate symbol svg sprite?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem too and could not find solution.
But found other gulp plugin [gulp-svg-symbols](https://github.com/Hiswe/gulp-svg-symbols) and it work very well.

[example](https://github.com/Hiswe/gulp-svg-symbols/tree/master/examples)

my config:

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var gulp = require('gulp');

module.exports = function(options) {
    return function() {
        return gulp.src(options.src)
            .pipe($.svgSymbols({
                id: "icon-%f"
            }))
            .pipe($.rename(function(file) {
                file.basename = 'sprite';
                return file;
            }))
            .pipe($.if( /[.]svg$/, gulp.dest(options.dest)));
    };
};
```